# How to search ionic storage for with city name and get city id

Tags: ionic3

I need assistance, I want to search ionic local storage in "citiesData" and get back city_id when a user location via geolocation returns city name.

Currently, I have my cities data loaded from the server on the initial page load and saved on local storage. On the next page load, we use local storage data

```
    getCitiesData() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this.storage.get('token').then((value) => {
                let headers = new Headers();
                headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
                headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + value);

                this.http
                    .get(ApiUrl + '/getCities', { headers: headers })
                    .pipe(map((res) => res.json()))
                    .subscribe(
                        (data) => {
                            this.cities = data.data;
                            this.storage.set('citiesData', data.data);
                            resolve(data);
                        },
                        (error) => {
                            reject(error);
                        }
                    );
            });
        });
    }
```

I want to get company_id and city_id when a user geo location returns the city name. This will be used when sending via api call to the backend.

Comment: You can get data from local storage and can set it into  a variable . If you want to get the data from local storage when the page loads, then mention it in the Angular life cycle hook NgOninit() . Then iterate through the Array using the city name and get company_id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up sending the city name to the backend and did a search on API post to get city id and assigned that variable to the required city_id field

Answer (score 0):

You should add each element to storage using as a key value pair such as

```
for(city in cities){
   storage.set(city.key, city.id) 
}
```

Then you can retrieve a spesific id by using

```
storage.get(city.key) //Returns the city.id
```